# Pynput Moving the Mouse in Minecraft

Tags: python, minecraft, macos-big-sur, pynput

I'm trying to create a macro in Minecraft and I need to move the mouse, but in-game, mouse.move(-100, 0) won't move the mouse. Outside of Minecraft I can move the mouse, but in-game I can't. I'm on macOS Big Sur and I don't think I have any more relevant info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. Here's another link that I just found and plan to use:

[How to control the mouse in Minecraft using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712139/how-to-control-the-mouse-in-minecraft-using-python)

Comment: I don't think raw input is a thing on mac. That's why I made a different question because I see raw input on Windows but not on mac. I'll edit this post when I trial the other methods